# Why do I get undefined: atomic.Bool

Tags: go

I see below error while building the code.

```
+ go build -a -ldflags '-X main.vendorVersion=vpcBlockDriver- -extldflags "-static"' -o /go/bin/ibm-vpc-block-csi-driver ./cmd/
# k8s.io/component-base/metrics
vendor/k8s.io/component-base/metrics/registry.go:35:29: undefined: atomic.Bool
note: module requires Go 1.19
```

All I did was to update dependencies to 1.26.1

This is the code base - https://github.com/ambiknai/ibm-vpc-block-csi-driver/tree/1.26
My go version  - `go version go1.20 linux/amd64`

Comment: My go version is 1.20

Comment: You're not using 1.20, otherwise the go tool wouldn't say "note: module requires Go 1.19". Check the output of `go version`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to upgrade your repo's Go version as it's still `1.18`.

Changing it in this file and re-compiling would work as it looks like your dev environment already has `1.20`

[image]